# Template.myTemplate.destroyed and .modal('hide') not work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

With new Meteor 0.8.0

If I use .destroyed (when change route) for hide a bootstrap modal, the tag

`<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>` remain in `<body>`.

With precedent version of Meteor all work ok...could be new live template engine (blaze)?

edit:

if I add to "Template.myTemplate.destroyed":

`$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');`

all works good...

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is due to Meteor being a single paged app. In the previous version it would go away and this was the 'bug'. The behaviour where it stays where it is is actually the correct behaviour.

When going to a new route you should close the modal. This should get rid of the div, or at least hide it.

```
$('#<modal-id>').modal('hide');
```

Comment: I have added $('#<modal-id>').modal('hide'); to onStop of IronRouter, but don't work...However I think that Template.myTemplate.destroyed is more correct for destroy modal, isn't it? FROM METEOR DOC: "This callback is most useful for cleaning up or undoing any external effects of created or rendered. It fires once and is the last callback to fire."